# LoadControl for same ascx control multiple times in a placeholder

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, user-controls

I have a UserControl that has a simple repeater inside.  It has a property called data which when passed into the control populates the repeater using the standard databinding.

On a page I have a placeholder.

I have a loop which does the following

```
        Dim qDetail As New UserControls_ReportDataTable
        qDetail = DirectCast(LoadControl("~/UserControls/ReportDataTable.ascx"), UserControls_ReportDataTable)
        qDetail.data = result
        phBCPSACustomQuestions.Controls.Add(qDetail)
```

Where result is different each time.

The problem is that at the end of the loop where I see my page all the instances of the control are populated with the last set of result data.

Any idea why this is happening?

--Update --

Just some further details based on comments.
The property "data" in the control is defined as follows:

Property data As IEnumerable

I have verified that the result is different in each loop iteration.

This is the full code for the loop itself

```
    For Each tblRow As DataRowView In dSet.Tables(0).DefaultView

        Dim result As DataView = dSet.Tables(1).DefaultView
        result.RowFilter = "QID = " & tblRow("QID").ToString


        Dim qDetail As UserControls_ReportDataTable
        qDetail = DirectCast(LoadControl("~/UserControls/ReportDataTable.ascx"), UserControls_ReportDataTable)
        qDetail.data = result
        phBCPSACustomQuestions.Controls.Add(qDetail)

    Next
```

Comment: Tip: the `New` on the first line is unnecessary. Also, post the property definition for "data".

Comment: You should show the complete loop, otherwise we must guess.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code I can't say for sure, but I'd guess that you are defining "result" outside of your loop and then setting it's value inside the loop.  This will lead to an "Access to Modified Closure" situation (don't know if that's just a resharper term or a global one).

In any case, define a variable inside the loop and set the value of the result there and then set it into your control.  It should solve your issue.

Comment: Note that this is no problem if the result variable is actually being set on each run through the loop. If the object it references is modified, however, that's a problem.

Comment: Very true, although without a more complete set of code, I had to take a guess at what he's doing.